# Material-Table scroll bar does not reset on table page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

When I scroll up or down in my Material-Table, and then change page, the vertical scroll bar is not reset to the top of the table.  Instead the scroll bar remains where it was before changing page.  This is causing confusion with people who are using my table.

The only scroll bar related props in the documentation for Material-Table is `doubleHorizontalScroll`, which forces the table's horizontal scroll bar to double in size.

Is there any way to reset the vertical scroll bar position when the page is changed?

This is the table:

```
<MaterialTable
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    icons={tableIcons}
    options={{
        columnsButton: true,
        pageSize: 25,
        pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100],
        padding: "dense",
        filtering: true,
        doubleHorizontalScroll: true,
        maxBodyHeight: "45rem",
        searchFieldStyle: {...},
        headerStyle: {...},
        rowStyle: (data, index) => {...},
    }}
    onChangePage={() => {
        tableRef.current.tableContainerDiv.current.scroll(0, 0); // this is the key!
    }}
    actions={[...]}
    components={{
        Toolbar: (props) => <CustomToolbarComponent {...props} />,
    }}
/>
```

[image: Edit elated-sinoussi-y29trc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered you may use a combination of `tableRef` and the `onChangePage` handler to do it:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const tableRef = useRef();
  
  const columns = []; // your columns

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      tableRef={tableRef} // <-- associate tableRef with MaterialTable
      columns={columns}
      data={[]}
      title="My Title"
      options={{ maxBodyHeight: '70vh' }}
      onChangePage={() => {
        tableRef.current.tableContainerDiv.current.scroll(0, 0); // this is the key!
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi João.  I get a the following error on `tableContainerDiv`: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tableContainerDiv')`

Comment: Hey @CiaranCrowley! Could you update your question with an example of the code you are testing or provide a CodeSandbox link?

Comment: I have added the table to the question.  I will have the Sandbox link soon.

Comment: Added the Sandbox link @JoãoVictorFSouza

Comment: You are missing the association of `tableRef` with `MaterialTable` component: `tableRef={tableRef}`. I'm updating my answer to point it out

Comment: I've also forked and updated your codesandbox example with the association and it's working! 
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cache-xfimx7